# Is trailing newline necessary in fgets?

Tags: c, newline, fgets

When I search using keywords of 'fgets' and 'newline', there are many posts regarding how to remove the trailing newline character (and such removal appears to be a burden). Yet it seems there is few explaination on how that newline is necessary for fgets to include. Also in C++, the 'std::getline' and 'std::istream:getline' methods will not keep the newline character. So is there a reason for it?

Comment: There's probably not any exceptional argument for why the original authors of C decided to include the newline character. It just is - it's what fgets() does. If the newline wasn't included, there would be someone else asking why it isn't included.

Comment: Thanks nos. I can take it as by design, just personally feel that it might not be a good one.

Comment: Note: `fgets()` will happily read and put in its buffer embedded `'\0'` and thus read 6 `char` and form a buffer like `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'`, `'\0'`, `'D'`, `'\n'`, `'\0'`.  Suspect `std::istream:getline` also nicely reads embedded `'\0'`.  IMO, `fgets()` not returning the length read is a greater deficiency.  `strlen()` is insufficient as it does accurately report the data read by `fgets()` in all cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is satisfying (IMHO) explanation:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

Especially:

> A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a valid character by the function and included in the string copied to str.

Comment: thanks for your comment. So it`s by design as "it is considered a valid character by the function and included in the string copied to str.". But this design drives people trying hard to remove the newline char, and C++ counterparts do not follow this design.

Comment: @Lyn But if it was removed, some other people would have to try hard to *preserve* the newline. People have different needs. And what C++ does, is not really relevant; Those are 2 different languages with different goals.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not necessary but if present it will be included in the returned line.

[The manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)  says:

> Reading stops after an `EOF` or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer. A terminating null byte (`'\0'`) is stored after the last character in the buffer.

So that's why it behaves that way.

Note that you can't *assume* that there will be a newline last in the buffer, you must check before removing it otherwise you risk truncating the last line if it didn't have a newline.

Comment: So that means if i end with EOF then nothing extra is stored, am i getting it right?