# Count number of letters in each word in a sentence with fgets() & strtok() in C

Tags: c, fgets, strtok

I have actually managed to count most of the words in a sentence except for the last word,
it somehow returns a value that is +1 of the actual letter count. I am unsure if it is because of a null pointer, or a hidden space somewhere, please help me understand how i can improve on the code to remove that error.

```
int main() {

    char strc[255];
    const char* delim = " ";
    char* token;
    int length;
    char* magic = "magic";

    printf("Enter a sentence, up to 255 characters:\n");
    fgets(strc, 254, stdin);
    token = strtok(strc, delim);

    while (token != NULL) {

        length = strlen(token);

        printf("%s %d\n", token, length);
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
    return 0;                       
}
```

the input and output is shown here:

input:
Potatoes are tasty

output:
Potatoes 8
are 3
tasty
 **6**

Comment: fgets returns the newline at the end of the string.  And you don't want to count that as a character.  So you need to remove the newline at the end of the string before tokenizing.  Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672134/is-trailing-newline-necessary-in-fgets

Comment: ... or include the newline as a delimiter.

Comment: @CarlNorum good point.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah i have actually looked through the references stated but i still have trouble forming the statements. they used strtok() functions, so does it mean in this case i have to add an if-else statement with strtok(token, '\n') to remove the newline??

Comment: Minus 1 not needed.  `fgets(strc, szieof strc, stdin);` is fine and preferable.

Comment: @Darryl No, just change `const char* delim = " ";` to `const char* delim = " \n";`

Comment: `printf("Enter a sentence, up to 255 characters:\n");` is off by 1.  Should be `printf("Enter a sentence, up to 254 characters:\n");`  if one includes the `\n` as one of the characters, else, `printf("Enter a sentence, up to 253 characters:\n");`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thank you for the tip!! ^^

Comment: @user3386109 okay! i'll try it out now!